# Extract string from brackets

Tags: bash, sed

I'm pretty new at bash so this is a pretty noob question..

Suppose I have a string:

```
string1 [string2] string3 string4
```

I would like to extract `string2` from the square brackets; but the brackets may be surrounding any other string at any other time.

How would I use `sed`, etc, to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $str | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
```

Comment: just to make sure I understand what's going on here (again, pretty noob at shell scripting: the first `cut` saves everything to the right of the [, and the second saves everything to the left of ]; those two together give me the string I want.

Answer (score 86):

Here's one way using awk:

```
echo "string1 [string2] string3 string4" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
```

This sed option also works:

```
echo "string1 [string2] string3 string4" | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g'
```

Here's a breakdown of the sed command:

```
s/          <-- this means it should perform a substitution
.*          <-- this means match zero or more characters
\[          <-- this means match a literal [ character
\(          <-- this starts saving the pattern for later use
[^]]*       <-- this means match any character that is not a [ character
                the outer [ and ] signify that this is a character class
                having the ^ character as the first character in the class means "not"
\)          <-- this closes the saving of the pattern match for later use
\]          <-- this means match a literal ] character
.*          <-- this means match zero or more characters
/\1         <-- this means replace everything matched with the first saved pattern
                (the match between "\(" and "\)" )
/g          <-- this means the substitution is global (all occurrences on the line)
```

Comment: This certainly works, but could you please explain what's going on?

Comment: Sure. I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @strictlyrude27 - i also added an example of using awk. It's similar to the accepted answer, but cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Why do we need to escape the brackets that group the sub-string of the matched string? Also, I thought that the closing square-bracket inside the character class has to be escaped, but only works without that!! I could not understand this.

Answer (score 25):

In pure bash:

```
STR="string1 [string2] string3 string4"
STR=${STR#*[}
STR=${STR%]*}
echo $STR
```

Comment: Would it be possible to obtain `[string2]` (extracting too the brackets) by using this shell operation method?

Comment: Yes. To get what's inside the brackets, including the brackets, do the following:  STR="[${STR#*\[}", that removes everything before the bracket, then STR="${STR%\]*}]", which removes everything after the bracket. The variable expansion removes the bracket, so you add one back in, inside the quotes.

Answer (score 24):

Specify awk multiple delimiters with **-F '[delimiters]'**

If the delimiters are square brackets, put them back to back like this **][**

```
awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'
```

otherwise you will have to escape them

```
awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}'
```

Other examples to get the value between the brackets:

```
echo "string1 (string2) string3" | awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}'
echo "string1 {string2} string3" | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's another one , but it takes care of multiple occurrences, eg

```
$ echo "string1 [string2] string3 [string4 string5]" | awk -vRS="]" -vFS="[" '{print $2}'
string2
string4 string5
```

The simple logic is this, you split on "]" and go through the split words finding a "[", then split on "[" to get the first field. In Python

```
for item in "string1 [string2] string3 [string4 string5]".split("]"):
    if "[" in item:
       print item.split("]")[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk example, but I'm matching on parenthesis which also makes it more obvious of how the -F works.

> echo 'test (lskdjf)' | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk`:

```
$ echo "string1 [string2] string3 [string4]" |
awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' 
string2
string4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Read file in which the delimiter is square brackets:
$ cat file
123;abc[202];124
125;abc[203];124
127;abc[204];124

To print the value present within the brackets:
$ awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}' file
202
203
204
```

At the first sight, the delimiter used in the above command might be confusing. Its simple. 2 delimiters are to be used in this case: One is [ and the other is  ]. Since the delimiters itself is square brackets which is to be placed within the square brackets, it looks tricky at the first instance.

Note: If square brackets are delimiters, it should be put in this way only, meaning first ] followed by [. Using the delimiter like -F '[[]]' will give a different interpretation altogether.

Refer this link: http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/07/awk-10-examples-to-read-files-with.html

Comment: Thanks for this. Have you any idea how to get the text between the **outermost** delimiters? So if the string is `x = (b + (c - d))` then it should pull out `b + (c - d)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Inline** solution could be:

```
a="first \"Foo1\" and second \"Foo2\""
echo ${a#*\"} | { read b; echo ${b%%\"*}; }
```

You can test in single line:

```
a="first \"Foo1\" and second \"Foo2\""; echo ${a#*\"} | { read b; echo ${b%%\"*}; }
```

**Output: Foo1**

Example with brackets:

```
a="first [Foo1] and second [Foo2]"
echo ${a#*[} | { read b; echo ${b%%]*}; }
```

That in one line:

```
a="first [Foo1] and second [Foo2]"; echo ${a#*[} | { read b; echo ${b%%]*}; }
```

**Output: Foo1**