# Extract string from square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I need to get the value **myfile.ext** from this example string: `'My message [file:myfile.ext]'`

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209629/extract-string-from-brackets), but couldn't manage to make the string returns empty string if the brackets are not in the string.

I need to check if the string contains `[file:***]` and return to the variable the `***` otherwise must be empty value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\[file:)[^]]*(?=])' file
myfile.ext
```

Which is the same as (depending if you are reading from a file or piping):

```
$ echo "'My message [file:myfile.ext]'" | grep -Po '(?<=\[file:)[^]]*(?=])'
myfile.ext
```

#### Explanation

It looks for the string coming after `[file:` and up to next `]`. To store it into a variable, use the `var=$(command)` expression:

```
result=$(grep -Po '(?<=\[file:)[^]]*(?=])' file)
```

it will be empty as default, and `myfile.ext` otherwise.

#### Sample

```
$ cat a
My message [file:myfile.ext
My message [file:myfile.ext]]a]

$ grep -Po '(?<=\[file:)[^]]*(?=])' a
myfile.ext
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it doesn't look _up to next ]_.  Your solution would return `myfile.ext` for an input `My message [file:myfile.ext`.

Comment: How come I didn't think for grep. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use -n flag of sed to supress printing all lines and then specifically use the p flag in the regex to print the match:

```
sed -n 's/\[file:\([^\]*\)]/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this BASH regex:

```
[[ "$s" == *[* ]] && [[ "$s" =~ \[[^:]*:([^\]]+)\] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
myfile.ext
```