# Extract string from brackets including the brackets

Tags: string, bash, shell

This question comes from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209629/extract-string-from-brackets).

String is:

```
string1 [string2] string3 string4
```

And I would like to **obtain**:

```
[string2]
```

this is, **including the brackets** `[` and `]`.

Preferred method: Bash shell operators, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209856/1461017).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

As a dirty and quick solution, just add back the brackets in result:

```
echo "[$STR]"
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the brackets, simply do the following:

```
astr="string1 [string2] string3"

astr=${astr/*[/[}
astr=${astr/]*/]}

echo "$astr"
```

**Output**

```
[string2]
```

---

It can also be done with `awk`, which is probably more robust because it will print out all strings surrounded by square brackets, for example:

```
astr="[string1] [string2] string3"
echo "$astr" | awk 'NR>1{print "["$1"]"}' RS=[ FS=]
```

**Output**

```
[string1]
[string2]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using awk**

```
echo "string1 [string2] [string3] string4"|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i~/^\[[^ ]+\]$/){print $i}}}'
```

output

```
[string2]
[string3]
```

**Using sed**

```
 echo "string1 [string2] [string3] string4"|sed -r 's/ *[^[ ]+[^]]( |$)//g;s/ +/\n/g'
```

output

```
[string2]
[string3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any regex solution in the answer you linked, so here you go:

```
str="string1 [string2] string3"
if [[ $str =~ \[.*\] ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
else
    echo >&2 "Not found!"
fi
```